# Weak law of large numbers works although first moment

Tags: probability-theory

I want to prove that the weak-law of large numbers hold if $X_{k}$ has the distribution:
$$\mathbb{P}\left(X_k\leq x\right) = \int_{-\infty}^x c\left(1+t^2\right)^{-1}\left(\log(1+t^2)\right)^{-1}dt
$$

The exercise is from Vardhan test book (Chapter 3 3.6). I don't know how should I prove this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let us observe that the distribution is symmetric since
\begin{align*}
P(-X_1\le x)
&=P(X_1\ge-x)\\
&=c\int_{-x}^\infty(1+t^2)^{-1}(\log(1+t^2))^{-1}dt\\
&=-c\int_{-x}^\infty(1+(-s)^2)^{-1}(\log(1+(-s)^2))^{-1}ds\\
&=c\int_{-\infty}^x(1+s^2)^{-1}(\log(1+s^2))^{-1}ds\\
&=P(X_1\le x).
\end{align*}
Since the distribution is symmetric, $n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\to0$ in probability as $n\to\infty$ if and only if $xP(|X_1|>x)\to0$ as $x\to\infty$ (see, for example, p. 235 of An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications by William Feller (Volume 2, Second Edition)). Since the distribution is symmetric, we have that $P(|X_1|>x)=2P(X_1>x)$. Hence, we need to show that $xP(X_1>x)\to0$ as $x\to\infty$. Using L'Hôpital's rule,
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{P(X_1>x)}{x^{-1}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-c(1+x^2)^{-1}(\log(1+x^2))^{-1}}{-x^{-2}}=0.
$$
We obtain
$$
\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\to0
$$
in probability as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! in that case i guess the strong law does not hold right? is it because the expectation doesn't exist?

Comment: @GiliBaumer You're welcome! Yes, it is an example when we only have the weak law of large numbers. The strong law of large numbers holds if and only if $\operatorname E|X_1|<\infty$ and in this example $\operatorname E|X_1|=\infty$. $n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$ converges in probability to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, but the expected value is undefined.

Comment: But, if i have the following property $E|X^+|=\infty$ and $E|X^{-}|<\infty$ then $n^{-1}S_{n}→\infty$ isn't it a contradiction to what you have just wrote?

Comment: @GiliBaumer A contradiction to what exactly? If $\operatorname EX^+=\infty$ and $\operatorname EX^-<\infty$, then $\operatorname E|X|=\infty$ and the SLLN does not hold.

Comment: If $EX_{k}^{+} = \infty$ and $EX_{k}^{-} < \infty$ then $S_{n}/n->\infty$ a.s. here the SLLN do hold right?

Comment: @GiliBaumer But the SLLN does not hold. By the SLLN I mean almost sure convergence of $n^{-1}S_n$ to some $c\in\mathbb R$. $n^{-1}S_n$ does not converge if $\operatorname EX^+=\infty$.

Comment: If $EX_{k}^{+} = \infty$ and $EX_{k}^{-} < \infty$ then $S_{n}/n->\infty$ a.s. here the SLLN do hold right? I think the name of this theorem is Erickson theorem. In our case I think the expectation is undefined and that is why SLLN does not hold.

Comment: @GiliBaumer No, it does not hold. We are arguing about the definition. When I say that the SLLN holds, I mean that $n^{-1}S_n\to c$ almost surely as $n\to\infty$, where $c\in\mathbb R$. A necessary and a sufficient condition for such a convergence is $\operatorname E|X|<\infty$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35384/discussion-between-gili-baumer-and-cm7f7bb).